Daily Reminding Notifications Using Unity 3D For Android
i am trying to create an app which displays the user mess menu of a particular college's hostel. There are four timings in it (breakfast, lunch, snacks, dinner) and each have their respective times.
I want to use android notification system to throw a notification whenever time for a particular meal occurs (say 7:00am for breakfast then it should say "Its Time For Breakfast")... I tried using push notifications but it requires internet... I also tried unity local notifications but the app must be in background (recent apps).
I want a offline solution in which user gets notified daily and isnt required to open the app (or have it be open in background) in order to receive notifications.
If there is any way to solve this problem then please help...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
